# Why BeautifulSoup response me a number, not code?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I tried to use BeautifulSoup to check if website updated. So, I want to know what will the program get from my code.
But after I ran my code:

```
import requests

html = requests.get("https://www.mangabz.com/60bz/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
code = soup.prettify()
result = code.find('<div class="container">')
print(result)
```

It responded a number:
1612

But I thought it should be like:

```
<a href="/m168608/" title="211試看版" style="color:#ff3f60;" target="_blank">211試看版 </a></span></span>]
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass tag name as first argument. Other attributes of tag are passed as a dictionary. Don't directly pass markup as argument

```
import requests
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get("https://www.mangabz.com/60bz/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
result = soup.find('div',{'class':'container'})

print(result)
```

> It responded a number: 1612

The mistake is on these lines :

```
code = soup.prettify()
result = code.find('<div class="container">')
```

`prettify` method returns a string not a `BeautifulSoup` object as you might have anticipated. string also has a `find` method which returns index of first occurrence of the substring (if found). In your case it found the match at index 1612.